# How to keep only first word of each list elements in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, slice

I have list that looks something like this

```
images =['atr5500-ve-7.8.1 version=7.8.1 [Boot image]' , 
'atr5300-ve-3.4.4','atr5600-ve-7.6.6','atr5300-ve-3.4.4',
'atr2300-ve-8.7.8','atr1200-ve-1.2.2','atr5600-ve-3.2.2']
```

basically I'm looking for that keyword that will help to get only the first word of all the elements in the list, which mean I'm expecting an output like this

```
images =['atr5500-ve-7.8.1' , 
'atr5300-ve-3.4.4','atr5600-ve-7.6.6','atr5300-ve-3.4.4',
'atr2300-ve-8.7.8','atr1200-ve-1.2.2','atr5600-ve-3.2.2']
```

I know that I have to use for loop and iterate through the list like `for i in list: list[i]= .....` , but not sure what to use to strip that individual list element and put back in the list.

Comment: `result = [s.split()[0] for s in images if s]`

Comment: @Thefourthbird ur solution worked for me, but I cannot mark your comment as answer. So I accepting another answer below which also worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regex as @mrxra suggested, but I think it's a bit overkill for that, simply use the `split()` method:

```py
images =['atr5500-ve-7.8.1 version=7.8.1 [Boot image]' ,
'atr5300-ve-3.4.4','atr5600-ve-7.6.6','atr5300-ve-3.4.4',
'atr2300-ve-8.7.8','atr1200-ve-1.2.2','atr5600-ve-3.2.2']

result = [
    im.split(" ")[0] for im in images
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

images =['atr5500-ve-7.8.1 version=7.8.1 [Boot image]' ,
'atr5300-ve-3.4.4','atr5600-ve-7.6.6','atr5300-ve-3.4.4',
'atr2300-ve-8.7.8','atr1200-ve-1.2.2','atr5600-ve-3.2.2']


print([re.sub(r'^([^\s]+).*$', '\\1', i) for i in images])
```

output:

```
['atr5500-ve-7.8.1', 'atr5300-ve-3.4.4', 'atr5600-ve-7.6.6', 'atr5300-ve-3.4.4', 'atr2300-ve-8.7.8', 'atr1200-ve-1.2.2', 'atr5600-ve-3.2.2']
```

Comment: *re* is overkill for this. str.split() will suffice

Comment: fair point...depends though on the assumption that the 3 provided sample lines give an adequate picture of possible inputs over time. regexes tend to be less brittle/easier to fix with regards to "unexpected" input. it's a personal preference though i admit.